# Maven and Eclipse global enviroment variable

Tags: eclipse, variables, maven, environment, workspace

I have got a path to some external program in my pom.xml, but this is annoying because if multiple people work with the pom through svn it always has to be changed and recommitted...

Can I somehow set some global eclipse variable (where?) and reference it through my pom (how?)?

Comment: What kind of programms do you have in your pom ?

Comment: Launch4j. The user will have to install this manually and then set some variable in eclipse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could define a system property like MY_PROG_PATH and [reference](http://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Properties) to it in your pom.xml with

```
${env.MY_PROG_PATH}
```

This should work inside and outside eclipse.

Comment: Okay but there are no variable in eclipse only?

Comment: @Franz Kafka I know about eclipse variables in the _Build Path / Libraries_ section but I doubt that these are propagated to your pom.xml file. Nevertheless I would not use an eclipse variable in the pom.xml - you only can build your project using eclipse in this case. A system property would be the better choice in my opinion.